# Which files/directories to ignore in a Laravel 4 project when using version control?

Tags: version-control, laravel, laravel-4

I have a [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) 4 project, and I would like to know which files should be ignored when using a version control software such as Git, Mercury or SVN?

The structure of my project looks like the following screen capture.

[image]

I'm pretty new to [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/) so I'm not very clear about what goes to a repo and what not. If someone can post their `.gitignore` file or their SVN ignore property, it could be handy.

Comment: i think you can stick with the default .gitignore provided by the framework. by default it will ignore the vendor directory, plus the composer things and some others. i also add the entire app/storage folder to .gitignore, just because i dont want to version control the sessions, compiled views, cache, logs etc.

Comment: Another good one to ignore is `workbench` if you use it. That directory should only be used to develop packages.

Comment: @thinkers: If I clone your repository, I'll end up *without* an app/storage directory. I might want that in some cases, and I might not want that in other cases. I don't want the cache, logs, etc, but I think I *do* want the app/storage directory itself in the repo on a Laravel project.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' instead you can add app/storage/<folder>/*  to your .gitignore for every single folder you want to version control, then add a .gitkeep file in each of them.

Comment: @thinkers: I thought that might be the way to go, but I haven't had time to try it. Thanks.

Comment: You no longer need to add the storage directories to /.gitignore since there are already .gitignore files in those directories. (As of Laravel 4.0.8)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For reference, that `.gitignore` file can be found [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.gitignore):

```
/bootstrap/compiled.php
/vendor
composer.phar
composer.lock  # Remove this one after you create a project
.env.*.php
.env.php
.DS_Store
Thumbs.db
```

As noted in the below comment, you probably want to commit `composer.lock` in your project. Laravel ignores it by default so the authors of the `laravel/laravel` package don't accidently impose packages on you.

Your project should include the `composer.lock` file so you can install packages of stable versions (via `composer install` instead of `composer update`) properly in your production environments.

Comment: "Commit your application's composer.lock (along with composer.json) into version control." -- http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-lock-the-lock-file

Comment: how about the **storage/*** folder?

Comment: I believe they are ignored already. Each directory within `app/storage/` contains a .gitignore file to handle that.

Comment: What about /vendor? Why would that be in the ignore file?

Comment: So you don't add it unnecessarily into version control. Composer can install dependencies onto your production server for you. (`composer install`). Note that `composer update` will update to latest dependencies and download them while `composer install` will install based on items in `composer.lock`. You should keep `composer.lock` in version control and use `$ composer install` in production to ensure you get the version of software you expect. (Running `composer update` also updates `composer.lock`).

Comment: i just got a laravel project i gotta work on.. and running `git st` i get all these [static files](http://pastebin.com/JzceSe20) in the `public/uploads` directory.. shouldn't I add `public/uploads/*` to my `.gitignore`??

Comment: @abbood - yep, you should definitely add that. You don't need those files in your git history.

Comment: It is also important to handle [Environment Variables](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration) correctly in Laravel. Check that link out if you want to update your answer.

Comment: Curious as to why compiled is in there. If I compile on my local, why recompile when I commit to production?

Comment: What about Composer autoload files? I noticed that files like:

`vendor/autoload.php`
`vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`
`vendor/composer/autoload_real.php`

are still in the repo. Is that OK?

Answer (score 2):

Note that the config file:

```
app/config/app.php
```

Has a cryptographic key in it that wouldn't be great to commit to a repository.  Or, at least, the file needs to be overwritten in production.

Comment: That key (or any other sensitive information) can be overridden in production or any other environment without touching `app/config/app.php`. Just create a dot file in the root of you project as: `.env.production.php` and Laravel will override defined in any config file. Docs: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration#protecting-sensitive-configuration

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to see the Laravel docs [here](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration) and [here](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#protecting-sensitive-configuration). This discusses how to setup different Laravel configurations for different environments and protect sensitive information.  All your `.env.local.php` type files should not be included in version control.  Note that the `.env.*.php` and `.env.php` is added in the default Laravel .gitignore file.  You can see it [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.gitignore)

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has posted their `.gitignore` on GitHub, which can be found [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.gitignore).

As of today, it looks like this:

```
/bootstrap/compiled.php
/vendor
composer.phar
composer.lock
.env.*.php
.env.php
.DS_Store
Thumbs.db
```

Comment: `composer.lock` should be removed from `.gitignore` (https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-lock-the-lock-file)

Answer (score 0):

GitHub has a repository of suggested .gitignore files for almost all kinds of projects at: http://github.com/github/gitignore

Alternatively, you can search it for your project using this handy and extremely useful online tool: http://www.gitignore.io